# Dell XPS13 screen almost completely dark

Tags: laptop, display, motherboard, hardware-failure, dell-xps

My Dell XPS 13 (9360, Intel UHD Graphics 620, Ubuntu 21.10) had the following hardware failure:

- On startup, the screen remained *almost* dark, i.e., if I dimmed the light, I was able to see everything, including colors (but just barely so).
- Software brightness changes were indicated but no changes in brightness happened.
- The integrated graphics test passed without complaining (and I was able to see it in a dark surrounding).
- Also the display's brightness was the same starting the BIOS on startup.
- The computer was perfectly working using an external monitor connected via HDMI.

My own uninformed guess would have been that my display's background light was broken.

I sent in the computer to Dell and now got the reply that the motherboard is broken, together with a quote to replace it.

**Question:** Is their diagnostics that the motherboard is broken reasonable given this setup?

Answer (score 1):

> I sent in the computer to Dell and now got the reply that the
> motherboard is broken, together with a quote to replace it.

Ask them if they guarantee the repair for 6 months or a year.

Normally a dim screen light is a backlight issue as you note. But if the backlight failed as the result of a motherboard circuit failure, then it could be the motherboard.

So two things:

(A) If you are willing to repair, you need a warranty that the repair is correct and will hold.

(B) If the repair is not economical, this may be the time to replace the computer.

I trust this helps your thinking.

Comment: Thanks, i will indeed ask them to guarantee their suggested approach fixes the issue. But it still seems unlikely that the motherboard works fine via an external monitor as this would indicate a motherboard failure would be very close to the connection to the laptop display.